# How to get loading time of data at frontend for any web application by using WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am having an web app & it have some hyperlinks are login.
I will click some links & it will fetch some data from database.

Now I want to calculate how much time it takes to fetch data at frontend (using Selenium WebDriver. Later I want to save time in any file for each of the link I clicked.

TIA.

Comment: Your code trials please.

Comment: I have no idea if WebDriver is having related APIs to achieve this or I have to use Java related classes only, LIke, getting system time before or after loading the page & minus to get the loading time. I want to know the best approach if WebDriver have it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) of using Selenium Web driver in JMeter,

You just need to call at start

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart(); //captures sampler's start time
```

and at the end:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

And it'll capture the time spend in sample.

Comment: I don't want to use Jmeter. Just by using WebDriver & Java, I want to calculate loading time after each click. Just want to know the approach to be used with WebDriver & Java.

Comment: But I gave the method to capture times in selenium web driver

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood. Let me give it a try & update you. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create one method to get the current system time and call it before and after your selenium code. The difference will be the time taken for the execution.you can use the below method for getting the current time .

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class time {

    public static void main(){
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf= new  SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain all the **`Performance and Network Statistics`** as reflected in the **`Chrome Development Tools`** injecting a **`JavaScript`** as follows :

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
String scriptToExecute = "var network = performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;";
String netData = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(scriptToExecute).toString();
System.out.println(netData);
```

Console Output :

```
[{redirectCount=0, encodedBodySize=218571, unloadEventEnd=0, responseEnd=3951.465, domainLookupEnd=2665.135, unloadEventStart=0, domContentLoadedEventStart=4213.63, type=navigate, decodedBodySize=218571, duration=8751.54, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=3116.0650000000005, toJSON={}, requestStart=3119.46, startTime=0, fetchStart=3951.855, domContentLoadedEventEnd=4222.57, entryType=navigation, workerStart=0, responseStart=3280.1150000000002, domInteractive=4213.565, domComplete=8742.91, domainLookupStart=2665.135, redirectEnd=0, transferSize=226167, connectStart=2665.135, loadEventStart=8743.550000000001, secureConnectionStart=2755.7250000000004, name=http://www.google.com/, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=navigation, loadEventEnd=8751.54}, {encodedBodySize=3123, entryType=resource, responseEnd=4204.990000000001, workerStart=0, responseStart=4074.295, domainLookupEnd=3983.2650000000003, domainLookupStart=3983.2650000000003, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=3123, duration=221.72500000000036, transferSize=3291, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=3983.2650000000003, toJSON={}, connectStart=3983.2650000000003, requestStart=3984.84, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2017/holidays-2017-day-2-5240850203279360-s.png, startTime=3983.2650000000003, fetchStart=3983.2650000000003, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=img}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=4704.6, workerStart=0, responseStart=0, domainLookupEnd=0, domainLookupStart=0, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=699.1949999999997, transferSize=0, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=0, toJSON={}, connectStart=0, requestStart=0, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png, startTime=4005.4050000000007, fetchStart=4005.4050000000007, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=css}, {encodedBodySize=23564, entryType=resource, responseEnd=4216.465, workerStart=0, responseStart=4119.075000000001, domainLookupEnd=4029.1900000000005, domainLookupStart=4029.1900000000005, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=65725, duration=187.27499999999964, transferSize=23713, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=4029.1900000000005, toJSON={}, connectStart=4029.1900000000005, requestStart=4030.8600000000006, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/logos/2016/slideshow/slideshow.15.js, startTime=4029.1900000000005, fetchStart=4029.1900000000005, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=script}, {duration=0, entryType=paint, toJSON={}, name=first-paint, startTime=4031.395000000001}, {duration=0, entryType=paint, toJSON={}, name=first-contentful-paint, startTime=4031.395000000001}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=5181.595, workerStart=0, responseStart=5179.5, domainLookupEnd=4213.19, domainLookupStart=4213.19, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=968.4050000000007, transferSize=42, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=4213.19, toJSON={}, connectStart=4213.19, requestStart=4214.135, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/gen_204?s=webaft&atyp=csi&ei=IcpAWvrYO5WcvQS6m7nQBw&rt=wsrt.3973,aft.239,prt.239, startTime=4213.19, fetchStart=4213.19, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=beacon}, {encodedBodySize=144968, entryType=resource, responseEnd=5178.63, workerStart=0, responseStart=4361.610000000001, domainLookupEnd=4225.935, domainLookupStart=4225.935, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=422973, duration=952.6949999999997, transferSize=145177, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=4225.935, toJSON={}, connectStart=4225.935, requestStart=4245.030000000001, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en.wVFdvIGaPg4.O/m=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,hsm,jsa,r,d,csi/am=wCL0eMEDkP8PgSLRFRwWLA0wDA0/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oFcejEpsXZHVqCUi53rHKPUdHFGrA, startTime=4225.935, fetchStart=4225.935, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=script}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=5198.755, workerStart=0, responseStart=0, domainLookupEnd=0, domainLookupStart=0, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=773.1800000000003, transferSize=0, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=0, toJSON={}, connectStart=0, requestStart=0, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/js/k=og.og2.en_US.LzK9bE9r_qo.O/rt=j/m=def/exm=in,fot/d=1/ed=1/rs=AA2YrTvGrVgDnAbvldCsR-LVadyTgN-6Lw, startTime=4425.575, fetchStart=4425.575, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=script}, {encodedBodySize=30130, entryType=resource, responseEnd=5490.6050000000005, workerStart=0, responseStart=5434.985000000001, domainLookupEnd=5306.4, domainLookupStart=5306.4, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=92899, duration=184.20500000000084, transferSize=30229, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=5306.4, toJSON={}, connectStart=5306.4, requestStart=5337.08, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en.wVFdvIGaPg4.O/m=d3l,udlg,aa,abd,async,dvl,foot,fpe,ipv6,lu,m,mu,sf,sonic,spch/am=wCL0eMEDkP8PgSLRFRwWLA0wDA0/exm=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,hsm,jsa,r,d,csi/rt=j/d=1/ed=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oFcejEpsXZHVqCUi53rHKPUdHFGrA?xjs=s1, startTime=5306.4, fetchStart=5306.4, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=script}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=5901.43, workerStart=0, responseStart=0, domainLookupEnd=0, domainLookupStart=0, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=594.165, transferSize=0, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=0, toJSON={}, connectStart=0, requestStart=0, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.com/textinputassistant/tia.png, startTime=5307.265, fetchStart=5307.265, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=img}, {encodedBodySize=850921, entryType=resource, responseEnd=8078.945000000001, workerStart=0, responseStart=5515.185, domainLookupEnd=5307.5, domainLookupStart=5307.5, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=850921, duration=2771.4450000000006, transferSize=851491, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=5307.5, toJSON={}, connectStart=5307.5, requestStart=5338.195000000001, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2017/holidays-2017-day-2-5240850203279360-5709068098338816-ssw.png, startTime=5307.5, fetchStart=5307.5, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=img}, {encodedBodySize=12361, entryType=resource, responseEnd=5513.750000000001, workerStart=0, responseStart=5499.31, domainLookupEnd=5307.675, domainLookupStart=5307.675, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=12361, duration=206.07500000000073, transferSize=12471, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=5307.675, toJSON={}, connectStart=5307.675, requestStart=5338.285000000001, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/logos/2016/slideshow/main-sprite-3.png, startTime=5307.675, fetchStart=5307.675, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=img}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=5803.495000000001, workerStart=0, responseStart=0, domainLookupEnd=0, domainLookupStart=0, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=459.420000000001, transferSize=0, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=0, toJSON={}, connectStart=0, requestStart=0, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.yoTdpQipo6s.O/m=gapi_iframes,googleapis_client,plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AAE/rs=AHpOoo9_VhuRoUovwpPPf5LqLZd-dmCnxw/cb=gapi.loaded_0, startTime=5344.075, fetchStart=5344.075, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=script}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=8078.380000000001, workerStart=0, responseStart=8077.755, domainLookupEnd=6182.910000000001, domainLookupStart=6182.910000000001, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=1895.4700000000003, transferSize=40, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=6182.910000000001, toJSON={}, connectStart=6182.910000000001, requestStart=6183.765, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/gen_204?atyp=i&ct=&cad=udla=1&ei=IcpAWvrYO5WcvQS6m7nQBw&di=2369&lt=-137922&ln=171221&zx=1514195497586, startTime=6182.910000000001, fetchStart=6182.910000000001, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=beacon}, {encodedBodySize=250301, entryType=resource, responseEnd=8727.245, workerStart=0, responseStart=8197.060000000001, domainLookupEnd=8104.39, domainLookupStart=8104.39, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=250301, duration=622.8550000000005, transferSize=250500, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=8104.39, toJSON={}, connectStart=8104.39, requestStart=8106.290000000001, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2017/holidays-2017-day-2-5240850203279360-5681717746597888-ssw.png, startTime=8104.39, fetchStart=8104.39, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=img}, {encodedBodySize=0, entryType=resource, responseEnd=8742.07, workerStart=0, responseStart=8741.205, domainLookupEnd=8104.6500000000015, domainLookupStart=8104.6500000000015, redirectEnd=0, decodedBodySize=0, duration=637.4199999999983, transferSize=40, redirectStart=0, connectEnd=8104.6500000000015, toJSON={}, connectStart=8104.6500000000015, requestStart=8106.845, secureConnectionStart=0, name=https://www.google.co.in/gen_204?atyp=i&ct=doodle&cad=d:68329420,c:0,e:1,t:-1,m:0,w:1,o:_&ei=IcpAWvrYO5WcvQS6m7nQBw&zx=1514195499507, startTime=8104.6500000000015, fetchStart=8104.6500000000015, nextHopProtocol=h2, initiatorType=img}]
```

> **Note** : The output being a **`String`** you can extract any of the parameter value and use it further.

- **`unloadEventStart`**
- **`domContentLoadedEventStart`** and **`domContentLoadedEventEnd`**
- **`duration`**
- **`requestStart`**
- **`fetchStart`**
- **`responseStart`** and **`responseEnd`**
- **`connectStart`** and **`connectEnd`**
- **`loadEventStart`** and **`loadEventEnd`**
- **`secureConnectionStart`**